# How to tell if an audio stream is encrypted or corrupted?

Tags: encryption

Is the following stream encrypted or corrupted? I was on a call and then this happened:

http://vocaroo.com/i/s0PlF2s8ULAU

Comment: Breaks in speech are clearly audible, which would not be desirable for an encrypted stream.

Comment: this may be better suited with a move to superuser

Answer (score 2):

To me that sounds like a specific type of corruption, which can also be used in simple "analog" audio encryption systems. Some analog encryption systems work by reordering of the frequency bands so they are unintelligible.

I believe what you are hearing is missing specific frequency bands, most likely by a fault in the encoder, which results in them not being transmitted. There appears to be a 4KHz highpass filter, which is common for voice frequency compression. There also appears to be a huge hole in the 120-320Hz range, where almost everything is missing except for a weak 150Hz band. This is what I believe is encoders fault, as there appear to be interference bands on the outer edge of the missing frequency range.

[image]

Simply missing that frequency range is not nearly enough to make human speech sound like noise. The speech pattern harmonics that are expected to be present in the 400 to 4000Hz range are missing. I believe a narrow frequency band has been expanded or duplicated across a wider range. Even with a frequency shift, there is just not enough actual sound data left to be useful.

This is functionally equivalent to taking a text file, and removing all but the middle 2 bits of each byte, then trying to read the text.

Comment: Nice analysis +1